# Calling a secured (authentication required) REST from django

Tags: python, django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework

I need to call a REST service from django where authentication (username + password) is required . I can get the password from request.user.password but it is not there in clean-text format but

`pbkdf2_sha256$36000$rOpm97qpHsy4$NFKCCfMmve1Z6c1U/grizJ6TyQck3bE/Fe+Gy3Gi+c8=`

(which is good from security point of view)
However as far as I know a secured REST service needs the clean-text password to perform the authentication so I cannot call it. I wouldn't be a big fan of storing the password when the user logs in.

How can a secured REST service be called from Django?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////// UPDATE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have a Django web application where the users can log in to (the REST has to be called from here).
Also I have a completely separate Spring Boot application that provides the REST interface. At the moment it is not secured but I want to implement authentication here.

Comment: Tell your REST service provider to issue Token or Session or Oauth based authentication other than Basic auth

Comment: Hi Raja, Thanks for the response! The REST provider is me too so I can tell myself anything. :) So in case of oauth no password has to be provided? However the password is needed first to build the token, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Django restframework authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages) for the better understanding. Actually this what happen in Oauth mechanism

Client will have to make GET request to user server and asking for code. They initially provide you the `client_id` and `redirect_url`

you will show them to enter the `username` and `password` and you will provide the code

After that client can make another post method to your server along with `client id` and `client secret` and your provide the `authentication token.`

Whenever user make some request with oauth token assume that user is authenticated user and provide the resource.

Comment: Hi Raja, thanks for the response! I updated the initial question as I might have forgotten to mention some important info. I have 2 separate applications and I want to call the REST service (which is in one the applications) from the Django one. To authenticate to the REST service I need the password (event only once). Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Try with token authentication that might help your needs.

Comment: Hi Raja, it is still not clear how to provide the password from Django as it is in encrypted format. Likely I should read a little bit more to understand how this whole authentication should work.